# Row Keys in Datasets: JoinAcross row keys; Demoting or deleting row keys

Tags: dataset, associations

I want to combine two datasets that share row keys but have different column keys. Visually, this looks like a JoinAcross on the row keys to me, but the column of row keys doesn't appear to be named. Can I perform this combination as a JoinAcross, or does it require a different function?

Also, the row keys are sometimes cumbersome--is there a way to demote them to normal rows?

**Example of desired dataset combination**

I have two datasets:

```
dsA = {<|"keyA" -> <|"key1" -> "a", "key2" -> "b"|>,
    "keyB" -> <|"key1" -> "c", "key2" -> "d"|>|>} // Dataset;
dsB= {<|"keyA" -> <|"key3" -> "a", "key4" -> "b"|>,
    "keyB" -> <|"key3" -> "d", "key4" -> "f"|>|>} // Dataset;
```

I want the join these such that I get a third dataset:

```
dsNew ={<|"keyA" -> <|"key1" -> "a", "key2" -> "b", "key3" -> "a", 
     "key4" -> "b"|>,
   "keyB" -> <|"key1" -> "c", "key2" -> "d", "key3" -> "d", 
     "key4" -> "f"|>|>} // Dataset
```

I have tried `JoinAcross[ dsA, dsB, Keys[dsA]]`, but this produces unclear errors.

**Example of desired Key demotion**

I have `dsA` again. I want to "demote" its row keys, such that I get:

```
{<|"RowKeys" -> "keyA", "key1" -> "a", "key2" -> "b"|>,
  <|"RowKeys" -> "keyB", "key1" -> "c", "key2" -> "d"|>} // Dataset
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Join` at level `3`:

```
dsC = Join[dsA, dsB, 3]
```

[image]

For the second part of the question:

```
Apply[KeyValueMap[<|"RowKeys" -> #, #2|>&]] @ dsA
```

[image]

```
Apply[KeyValueMap[<|"RowKeys" -> #, #2|>&]] @ dsC
```

[image]

Comment: The Apply method works for a two row dataset, but appears to fail for datasets with more than two rows. For example, if I say `dsC=Join[dsA,dsB,3]` and then use the above `Apply` method, I get a Failure: `KeyValueMap[Association[RowKeys->#1,#2]&] called with 2 arguments; 1 argument is expected.`

Comment: @KBL, posted what i get when I use `Apply[KeyValueMap[<|"RowKeys" -> #, #2|>&]] ` on `dsC`  on v12 /Wolfram Cloud.

Comment: you are right, I typed the wrong thing. What I *meant* to type was that the Apply method doesn't work when there are more than 2 rows--if I have `dsD=Join[dsA,dsB]` (without the 3) and type `Apply[KeyValueMap[<|"RowKeys" -> #, #2|>&]]@dsD`, I get `KeyValueMap[Association[RowKeys->#1,#2]&] called with 2 arguments; 1 argument is expected.`

Comment: @KBL, looks like changing `Apply` to `Map` works for both cases.

Comment: Thanks very much for the answers here and on the other question. As I posted on the other page, I found a nasty dataset wrinkle that was causing my dataset to be especially uncooperative. With your help, though, I have the answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
    Merge[{Normal@dsA, Normal@dsB}, Join @@ # &] // Dataset
```