# Changing Row Keys into Normal Rows

Tags: dataset, associations

I have a dataset with column and row keys:

```
dsA={<|"keyA" -> <|"key1" -> "a", "key2" -> "b"|>, 
  "keyB" -> <|"key1" -> "c", 
    "key2" -> "d"|>|>, <|"keyC" -> <|"key1" -> "a", "key2" -> "b"|>, 
  "keyB" -> <|"key1" -> "d", "key2" -> "f"|>|>}//Dataset
```

[image]

Because the row keys get in the way of a number of operations (such as joining with other datasets that might have a different number of rows), I want to change the dataset to the following form:

[image]

I asked this as an [addendum to a different question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/203117/row-keys-in-datasets-joinacross-row-keys-demoting-or-deleting-row-keys), but so far no luck. I can create datasets of the values and the keys:

```
dsValues = dsA[Values]
dsKeys = dsA[Keys]
```

But I'm not sure how to put the `dsKeys` column in front of the `dsValues` table.

Answer (score 9):

```
Map[KeyValueMap[<|"RowKeys" -> #, #2|>&]] @ dsA
```

[image]

Also

```
dsA[All, KeyValueMap[<|"RowKeys" -> #, #2|>&]]
```

> same result

Answer (score 7):

Like this:

```
dsA[Flatten, KeyValueMap[Prepend[#2, "keys" -> #] &]]
```

?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @kglr and @Kuba for their correct answers--I post this longer response to highlight an issue with brackets in datasets that I wasn't aware of. Apparently, you can make datasets in a couple of different ways--with a leading `{` bracket or without. Let's say we have two datasets (slightly modified versions of the one from my original question):

```
dsBracket = {<|
    "keyA" -> <|"key1" -> "a", "key2" -> "b"|>, 
    "keyB" -> <|"key1" -> "c", "key2" -> "d"|>,
    "keyC" -> <|"key1" -> "a", "key2" -> "b"|>, 
    "keyD" -> <|"key1" -> "d", "key2" -> "f"|>|>} // Dataset
```

and

```
dsNoBracket = <|
   "keyA" -> <|"key1" -> "a", "key2" -> "b"|>, 
   "keyB" -> <|"key1" -> "c", "key2" -> "d"|>,
   "keyC" -> <|"key1" -> "a", "key2" -> "b"|>, 
   "keyD" -> <|"key1" -> "d", "key2" -> "f"|>|> // Dataset
```

Note that the only difference is the `{}` on `dsBracket`.

[image]

I didn't realize that my dataset was lacking that bracket because I imported data and manipulated it all within the dataset environment--I'd prefer to ignore the mess! The datasets `SemanticImport` with the `{`; the dataset first loses the curly brace when I `SelectFirst` the result of a `GroupBy`.

@Kuba's method works for `dsBracket`, but produces a failure for the `dsNoBracket`. With @kglr's answer, I realized something weird was happening. Here's what happens with and without the bracket (and my workaround for the issue):

[image]

Comment: you can use `dsBracket[All,KeyValueMap[<|"RowKeys" -> #, #2|>&]]` and `dsNoBracket[KeyValueMap[<|"RowKeys" -> #, #2|>&]]` for the two cases.

Comment: Well, you get what you asked for :) If the dataset structure is different then you need to adapt the solution. If you take a look at my and @kglr 's results with the original `dsA` you can apply `Normal` to see that our results differ. I added `Flatten` on purpose to get rid of nested lists. At the end the question is, what is your input and desired output exactly?